# Ajax Ошибка Gif89a

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, yii2

На одном из пяти компьютерах при отправке ajax запроса приходит ответ GIF89a.... Погуглил, вроде как какая то ошибка но ничего толком не нашел. Может кто то сталкивался? в методе ajax.php ничего особенного нету, одна выборка с базы и в принципе все, причем интересно что на оставшихся 4 пк все отлично работает

Comment: Плохо искали.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597082/how-is-a-website-hacked-by-a-maliciously-encoded-image-that-contained-a-php-scr

Comment: Извиняюсь конечно, но может конкретно Вы можете подсказать мне, как помочь?

Comment: Поделитесь кодом пожалуйста, чтобы было удобнее работать над ошибками. Гадать ведь не будем

Comment: Уже на этом этапе все плохо

$.ajax({
                                url: '/arenda/default/check_for_view_ad_name',
                                type: "POST",
                                data: ({cat_id:$(".ad_cat").val()}),
                                success: function(html){
                                   html = html.split(';');
                                        console.log(html[1]);
                                }
                            });

Comment: public function actionCheck_for_view_ad_name()
    {
        $cat_id = Yii::$app->request->post('cat_id');
        $result = ModArendaTree::findOne(['id' => $cat_id]);
        while ($result->use_name_for_ads != 1) {
            if ($result->parent_id != 0) {
                $result = ModArendaTree::findOne(['id' => $result->parent_id]);
            } else return 0;
        }
        if ($result->use_name_for_ads == 1) $name = $result->name_for_ads;
        else $name = 'none';
        return $result->use_name_for_ads . ';' . (empty($name) ? 'Название объявления' : $name);

    }

Comment: Добавь пожалуйста в вопрос с форматированием

Comment: Я не могу этого сделать) При ответе на комментарий не пойму как сделать...